# Incorrect values functions

Tags: php, arrays, max, min

I have a problem with a script, the script read a file (CSV) and stores the last value of each line in an array, then I calculate the maximun, minimun and average of the values in the array, but with big files the script give me an incorrect value for the maximun and minimun, here you can download the script and two files, with the file 8.csv the calculations are correct but with the file 1.csv the values are wrong, the only difference I see is that the file 1.csv is much larger than the other.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$variable2=file("1.csv");
$i=0;
foreach($variable2 as $var){
    if($i==0){
        $i++;
    }else{
        $datos=explode(",",$var);
        $valor=$datos[count($datos)-1];
        if($valor!= -3000){
            $todos[$i-1]=$valor;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

$promedio=array_sum($todos) / count($todos);
$maximo=max($todos);
$minimo=min($todos);
echo "MAXIMO = ".$maximo." MINIMO = ".$minimo." PROMEDIO = ".$promedio;

?>
```

And this is a part of the file the script read:

```
OBJECTID,pointid,grid_code,potrero_ID,MOD13Q1.A2
7300.0,7300.0,1.0,1,6431
7498.0,7498.0,1.0,1,6684
7499.0,7499.0,1.0,1,6431
7500.0,7500.0,1.0,1,6431
7501.0,7501.0,1.0,1,6431
7502.0,7502.0,1.0,1,6431
7503.0,7503.0,1.0,1,6431
7504.0,7504.0,1.0,1,6304
7697.0,7697.0,1.0,1,6734
7698.0,7698.0,1.0,1,6734
7699.0,7699.0,1.0,1,6127
7700.0,7700.0,1.0,1,6127

Expected values:

Maximun: 9307
Minimun: -650
Average: 6555,211347

Output values:

Maximun: 999
Minimun: -104
Average: 6555,3296310272
```

Comment: Please post your code in here, so we can quickly view and suggest the proper answer over it, rather downloading that zip file. In an overview what I consider a problem to your solution would be, after you load all the values from the CSV into an array, you can `max()`, `min()`, `array_sum()/count($arr)` to achieve this

Comment: @user953851 Could you also post the expected and actual output? (Only the part that is failing)

Comment: That is what i do, but with larger files don't work , that is why i put the files to download

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try on this code

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $todos = array();
    $datos = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $valor=$datos[count($datos)-1];
        if($valor != -3000){
            $todos[]=$valor;
        }
    }
    $promedio=array_sum($todos) / count($todos);
    $maximo=max($todos);
    $minimo=min($todos);
    echo "MAXIMO = ".$maximo." MINIMO = ".$minimo." PROMEDIO = ".$promedio;
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Here I made use of [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv)(); that reads the file handle and returns the array of entire row CSV which we can iterate over, then I initialized `$dotos = array();` once within which values are entered if the condition becomes true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i solve the problem with this line:$valor=intval($datos[count($datos)-1]);